# Angular directive for simple animation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a template, inside that template is div with the class `big-box` and it's inside a div container called `.movie-container`.

Template,

```
.movie-container
  .big-box
```

I want to animate the `.big-box` element to a height of 300px (from 0px) when a user clicks on the `.movie-container`.

I've tried to setup a directive with a click function but it's not working. When I click on the `.big-box` div it doesn't show the `click` in the console log.

```
app.directive('big-box', [function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.bind('click', function() {
        console.log ('click')
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

So I could use some tips.

Comment: What does "it's not working" means ? Do you have an error message ? Or is it not behaving like expected ?

Comment: It is not behaving as expected. I expect that when I click on the `.big-box` div that the console would log 'click'. But that is not happening.

Comment: Did you load the directive in your view? (something link `<div big-box class="big-box">click me</div>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naming convention used for the directive is not correct. You have to use camel case while defining your custom directives.

```
app.directive('bigBox', [function() {   // Use camel case 
  return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.bind('click', function() {
        console.log ('click')
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

and in your html you need to use it like this :

```
<div class="movie-container">
    <div big-box>  <!-- using the directive -->
       click here
    </div>
 </div>
```

The name must be written using dashes and each dash represents a capital letter from the directive definition. It is a angularjs convention.

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xgv86qj6/).

Comment: The part about the naming of the directive is correct, but he can use it as a class, attribute or element.

Comment: Thanks, going to try it out tonight. Can I just use jquery in that directive to control animation on elements?

Comment: See the angular.element [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element). If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function. You might want to use toggleClass() or addClass() to create the animation.